# Difference between default launch policy and std::launch::deferred

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, asynchronous, std

I wrote some code to diagnose the difference betweendefault launch policy and std::launch::deferred.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    auto func = [] { 
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << "," << std::flush; 
        int i=std::numeric_limits<int>::max(); 
        while(i--); 
        std::cout << "b" << std::flush;
    };

    std::vector<std::future<void> > vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      vec.push_back(std::async( std::launch::deferred, func ));
    }
    for (auto &t : vec) {
      t.get();
    }

}
```

the output of above code is:

> 140257438672704,b140257438672704,b140257438672704,b140257438672704,b140257438672704,b140257438672704,b140257438672704,b140257438672704,b140257438672704,b140257438672704,b

```
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    auto func = [] { 
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << "," << std::flush; 
        int i=std::numeric_limits<int>::max(); 
        while(i--); 
        std::cout << "b" << std::flush;
    };

    std::vector<std::future<void> > vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      vec.push_back(std::async( func ));
    }
    for (auto &t : vec) {
      t.get();
    }

}
```

the output of above code is:

> 140200948524864,b140200948524864,b140200948524864,b140200948524864,b140200948524864,b140200948524864,b140200948524864,b140200948524864,b140200948524864,b140200948524864,b

It still ran task on the main thread.
My question is why it doesn't schedule more thread to run faster when using default launch policy(my machine got 4 cores)?

Comment: Why not use `std::this_thread::sleep_for` instead of this horrible `while(i--);` ?

Answer (score 2):

According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) when you don't explicitly pass a policy:

> 1) Behaves the same as async(std::launch::async | std::launch::deferred, f, args...). In other words, f may be executed in another thread or it may be run synchronously when the resulting std::future is queried for a value.

And when both flags are enabled:

> If both the std::launch::async and std::launch::deferred flags are set in policy, it is up to the implementation whether to perform asynchronous execution or lazy evaluation.

So, the difference is that by default, the policy is to launch either deferred or asynchronous. The choice is up to the implementation. When the policy is deferred, then lauch can only be deferred.

> My question is why it doesn't schedule more thread to run faster when using default launch policy(my machine got 4 cores)?

It's not required to, and the implementation chose not to.

Comment: Is it possible to change the launch policy to `launch::deferred` _globally_, so that I don't have to sprinkle all my code at each location where I consume a future?